# Qlik Sense: Loading d3.js dependancy

Tags: requirejs, qliksense

I'm simply trying to load d3 into a Qlik Sense extension and running into issues, hoping someone can help as I'm sure it's relatively simple.

My template.html looks like this:

```
<div qv-extension style="height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: auto;" class="ng-scope">

    {{ html }}
    <div class="mydiv">

    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code looks like the below:

```
define( ["qlik",
        "jquery",
        "text!./style.css",
        "text!./template.html",
        "./d3/d3",
    ],
    function (qlik, $, cssContent, template ) {'use strict';
   $("<style>").html(cssContent).appendTo("head");
    return {
   template: template,
   initialProperties : {
            qHyperCubeDef : {
                qDimensions : [],
                qMeasures : [],
                qInitialDataFetch : [{
                    qWidth : 10,
                    qHeight : 500
                }]
            }
        },
        definition : {
            type : "items",
            component : "accordion",
            items : {
                dimensions : {
                    uses : "dimensions",
                    min : 0
                },
                measures : {
                    uses : "measures",
                    min : 0
                },
                sorting : {
                    uses : "sorting"
                },
                settings : {
                    uses : "settings",
                    items : {
                        initFetchRows : {
                            ref : "qHyperCubeDef.qInitialDataFetch.0.qHeight",
                            label : "Initial fetch rows",
                            type : "number",
                            defaultValue : 500
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        support : {
            snapshot: true,
            export: true,
            exportData : true
        },
        paint: function ( ) {
            console.log("painting...");

            var svg = d3.select(".mydiv")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        },
        controller: ['$scope', function (/*$scope*/) {
        }]
    };

} );
```

and the error i get in the dev tools look like this:
[image: Error message in dev tools console]

My folder structure is: 
[image: Folder structure, see the directory bar]

What am I doing wrong? Why can't it see the d3 file?

Answer (score 0):

adding d3 as an argument to your function:

```
 function (qlik, $, cssContent, template , d3)
```

resolved this issue